# Autohotkey - Gamepad as Mouse - how to use osk.exe (On Screen Keyboard)

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, autohotkey, gamepad

I've mapped my Analogs to Moving the Mouse Cursor,
and `Joy5` to `LButton` (etc.), and `Joy11` to `Run,%windir%\system32\osk.exe`

Everything works well, except one thing:

- Inside window of osk.exe, the pressing of  mapped `Joy5` does not work as expected `LButton`, so I can't type any text by my Gamepad.

How to fix that?

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try so far? Did you debug the program? Did the hotkey fire when you looked at the key history? Please address these questions.

Comment: `Joy5::LButton` and `Joy11::Run,%windir%\system32\osk.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing standard `osk.exe` from Windows by other software `freevk.exe` solved the problem.